# 12.04, mapping network drive from windows server 2003

Tags: networking, 12.04, mount, samba

I'm trying to map a network drive running on a windows server..

I tried using the Connect to Server GUI but didn't get anywhere so I tried mounting it in the terminal but have had little success.

basically here are the details of the server I am trying to connect to and what I have tried:
(in fstab)

```
SERVER=10.26.136.12
SHARE=8279
MOUNTPOINT=/home/jacobian/mystuff
FS_TYPE=cifs
SMB_CREDENTIALS=/home/jacobian/.smbcredentials
```

(.smbcredentials)

```
username=[domain]/[myusername]
password=[mypassword]
```

when I try to mount using

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.26.136.12/8279 /home/jacobian/mystuff -o credentials=/home/jacobian/.smbcredentials
```

I get Mount error(13) permission denied.

My credentials are correct because when I log into a windows machine and type
\10.26.136.12\8279 and use [myusername]@[domain] [mypassword] it connects and works correctly.

Any help with what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to convert my work computer over to ubuntu and this is what makes or breaks it.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Having had the exact same problem, installing the package samba4-clients resolved everything and now everything works as before the upgrade when I was on Oneiric Ocelot

so, all I did was:

```
    sudo apt-get install samba4-clients
```

Comment: I installed samba4-clients and re-tried the mount command but received the following error:
**mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //10.26.136.12/8279,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
       need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so'**

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the share via Nautilus? This might bring some clues... Open nautilus-> Press alt to get to the menu, use the command `connect to server` and enter your information there

Answer (score 1):

It's weird - in Ubuntu 12.04 I'm also having problems connecting to Windows Shares with the Connect to Server GUI.  Most of the time, I just can't connect to the Windows Shares!

But if, in the **Connect to Server** GUI, I use...

**Server:** MyServerIPAddress; **Type:** Windows Share; **Share:** c$; **Folder:** /; **Domain Name:** MYDOMAIN (*in capital letters*); **User Name:** MyUserName@MyDomain.local; **Password:** MyPassword

...then somehow I've been connecting to Windows Shares, some of the times!

But if I use the Server's name (instead of IP address), and if I use just MyUserName (without @MyDomain.local), then I can't connect to any Windows Shares at all.

And that's on 2 newly-upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 PC's - one at work and one at home.  Both have the same problem.

Comment: Dunno if it helps, but I noticed one of my failed attempts at connecting a Windows Share eventually returned the following error: _DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply.  Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken._

Comment: But all other times, it just says: _Please verify your user details._

Comment: i can confirm this to be a problem on my newly upgraded 12.04 ubuntu box.
Also using the above tips it works for me even without @domainname in the username (just DOMAINNAME in capital letters in the domain field and using IP instread of DNS name...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me was to remove the domain from the username and add it in as a separate parameter: domain = whatever.

As stated in an answer above: **upper case the domain name**!!! .... this appears to be a new gotcha in Precise not present in older versions.

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding a separate line to the smbcredentials file but it still says permission denied. I also tried surrounding the credentials in quotations but that didn't help either....